# Dynamic images and databinding

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc

Imagine having a dataset with data which binds to the report - works just fine.

Now, I wish to add into another dataset dynamically or dynamic parameters. These parameters, or dataset, will contain images. The images are in a byte array.

I am unable to get them to display in the RDLC report when generated.

This is what I have done so far:

- Obtain the byte[] array, in code, from an external source (a URL)
- Convert the byte[] array of the image to Base64String
- Add this as a ReportParameter

Then in the RDLC, I added this parameter and then added an image control.
Then for this image box/control, for the value I set it to the following:

- =System.Convert.FromBase64String(Parameters!TheImage.Value)

However I just get rendered an "X" for the image as if the image was not found but it definitely is there.

The code to render the report is more or less the following (only pasted import bits):

```
using (var rv = new ReportViewer())
            {
                rv.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                rv.Reset();
 using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\MyReport.rdlc"))
                {
                    rv.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(sr);
 rv.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;        
                    var

 reportParameters = new List<ReportParameters>();
reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter("TheImage", Convert.ToBase64String(TheExternalImage.Image);
rv.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);

 string mimeType;
                    string encoding;
                    string fileExtension;
                    string[] streamIds;
                    Warning[] warnings;
                    var streambytes = rv.LocalReport.Render(format.ToString(), null, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileExtension, out streamIds, out warnings);
                    rv.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain();
}
}
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do this convert your image byte array into a base 64 string and pass that string into the parameter (you are already doing this). Then set the image to have it's source as Database and make sure you set the MIME type correctly on the image field then use the parameter as the source.

Most likely it is setting the image source to Database that you are missing.

[image]

Comment: thanks  - problem is that the image is NOT from the database. it is from an external source being passed into the RDLC. The MIME type is already set correctly.